# Use of workflow management system like oozie to process spark system sub components

Tags: apache-spark, oozie, apache-spark-sql

I need your suggestion for a system that we are building on spark. Our use case is as follows.

1. We have four independent business rules that we need to calculate.
2. Every business rule consists of operation like reading from several table and joining and aggregating them and producing one output table.
3. Intermediate output results of each business rule we need to combine with each other and produce final output. For example we need to combine say rule1 and rule2 result and then rule3 and rule4 followed by combining their result as final output. Let's call these steps as combining steps.

So this seems to be a DAG (Direct acyclic graph) that we need to process where rules become initial nodes to process followed by combining steps that has to be executed in some order.

Now the question is, should I consider a work-flow management system like Oozie as technology choice to process this DAG? For e.g. in Oozie all individual rules will be become independent "actions" and combining steps will be dependent "actions" that should run post business rule actions.  If I follow this, my system will be decoupled in several independent sub-component; all will be configured in Oozie xml file. 
This sounds fascinating but I am not very convinced for above approach. "My" reasons are -
1. Each layer has to create independent SparkContext, single spark context can not be shared across all steps.
2. Spark in itself is nothing but process a DAG. Using Oozie on top of this would be an over kill.
3. Oozie should be used for use cases where we need to build a workflow for different components. For e.g. I want to call spark application followed by some shell script followed by Pig script and so on.

If I don't use a work-flow management system like Oozie, I need to write small framework in my application that combines these rules in that order. Of-course in future course of action if I need to run rules in parallel, I need to modify my this tiny framework.

So my questions are - 
1. Do my reasons of not using Oozie correct? 
2. If not Oozie, there is another framework that fits in my use case? 
3. Does Writing my small framework to handle this workflow is actually reinventing the wheel?